# How to remove settings option in navigation drawer activity in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-webview

I made a web view app with navigation drawer and it is working fine but the only problem is the settings option in the right corner... Can I edit or remove it??

please check the pics : https://ibb.co/mVqbRR
https://ibb.co/n8d7Y6

Comment: post your code activity_main .xml

Comment: i posted it check it.. thanks

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks I removed WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mywebview"/>             from activity main and it is working fine

Comment: you want to remove or what? post your code and explain what is your problem, to better understand to every one

Comment: Check the links i posted

Comment: OK I understand..Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in res / menu / main.xml

Answer (score 3):

In your **MainActivity** you will have `optionmenu`, just make it false

```
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       return false;
 }
```

I hope this will solve your problem..

Comment: it's not a settings option in the right corner...The button name called `overflow menu`.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way. This code works fine for me

```
    myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.clearCache(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.clearCache(true);
    myWebView.clearHistory();
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new ProgressWeb(getActivity()));
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```